# How can i get the same functionality as this .each() using a for loop?

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have written this function to assign line-height to elements with different heights.Is there any possible way of doing this using a for loop ?

```
$(".portfolio-image-overlay").each(function(){
    "use strict"; 
    var height = $(this).siblings("img").height();
    var cheight = $(".item.active> a> img").height();
    $(this).css({"line-height":height+"px"});
    $(this).css({"line-height":cheight+"px"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
var portfolio = $(".portfolio-image-overlay");
for(var i=0;i < portfolio.length;i++){
   var _this = portfolio.eq(i);
   var height = _this.siblings("img").height();
   var cheight = $(".item.active> a> img").height();
   _this.css({"line-height":height+"px"});
   _this.css({"line-height":cheight+"px"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a for loop actually. The .each() function loops through the $(".portfolio-image-overlay") resultset.

You would be looking at something like this

```
var resultSet = $(".portfolio-image-overlay");
for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
    console.log(resultSet[i]);
}
```

Also, its smart to store the jQuery pointers in variables; Calling **$(this)** three times is less efficient than

```
var that = $(this);
```

and using that 3 times.

I see you're also doing that with the active item;

```
$(".portfolio-image-overlay").each(function(){
    "use strict"; 
    var height = $(this).siblings("img").height();
    var cheight = $(".item.active> a> img").height();
    $(this).css({"line-height":height+"px"});
    $(this).css({"line-height":cheight+"px"});
});
```

This would be faster;

```
var activeItem = $(".item.active> a> img");
$(".portfolio-image-overlay").each(function(){
    "use strict"; 
    var that = $(this);
    var height = that.siblings("img").height();
    var cheight = activeItem.height();
    that.css({"line-height":height+"px"});
    that.css({"line-height":cheight+"px"}); //Don't know why you're doing this twice, maybe you've CSS animated it so i'll keep it there
});
```

EDIT:

Fastest would be as such;

```
var resultSet = $(".portfolio-image-overlay");
var cheight = $(".item.active> a> img").height();
for(var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i ++){
    var current = resultSet.eq(i);
    var height = current.siblings("img").height();
    current.css({"line-height":height+"px"}).css({"line-height":cheight+"px"});
}
```